# Efficient Frame-Cutting Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Came across problem that initially seemed pretty simple; however, I couldn't find an efficient solution. Can you guys help?

---

A sheet is comprised of rectangles (frames) of various lengths and widths that may have gaps but do not intersect. Find the least amount of straight cuts (vertical or horizontal) that separate those rectangles. Cuts have to be made through the entire available board.

Input consists of the number of rectangles followed by top-left and bottom right coordinates of each one. Output should have the number of cuts followed by 2 points representing vertical/horizontal cut or NA if there was no solution. Note that several optimal solutions are possible.

**Input:**

(3,3)

(0,0) (1,1)

(2,0) (3,1)

(0,2) (3,3)

**Output:**

2

(0,2) (2,2)

(1,0) (1,2)

**Input:**

(5,5)

(0,0) (3,1)

(4,0) (5,3)

(0,2) (1,5)

(2,4) (5,5)

**Output:**

NA

Answer (score 3):

It is a classic example of Cutting Stock problem solved by P. Y. Wang's bottom-up two-dimensional algorithm (as one possible approach).

Google search links usually lead to paid-access articles, but some [publically available](http://www.silvaco.com/tech_lib_TCAD/simulationstandard/1999/mar/a2/a2.html) descriptions can be found as well ([PDF version](http://www.silvaco.com/tech_lib_TCAD/simulationstandard/1999/mar/mar1999.pdf), p.6)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you want to slightly modify your answer, I think the problem is a more specific version of the Cutting Stock problem. **The Guillotine problem** required only making cuts that continue all the way across each sheet which is the case in the problem above.

Comment: @user2961443: Yes. That's exactly what hierarchical pairwise merging algorithm with rectangular intermediate solutions generates: guillotine cutting patterns.